# How to Sort an Array of Objects containing References to Other Objects that Should Come First?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, multidimensional-array

#### **How can I sort an array of objects containing references to other objects in the same array that should come first?**

I have an array of objects that need to be sorted by two factors:

1. **An object should come after all of its "members"** ("members" are references to the "name" of other objects in the same array).
2. Then, where it could not be sorted by the criteria above, it should be sorted in **alphabetical order by "name"**.

For example, consider the following [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```js
const example = [
  // This object named "Example 1" should come after its members ("Example 4"):
  {
    name: 'Example 1',
    members: [
      'Example 4',
    ],
  },
  // This object named "Example 2" should come after its members ("Example 1" and "Example 3"):
  {
    name: 'Example 2',
    members: [
      'Example 1',
      'Example 3',
    ],
  },
  // This object named "Example 3" does not have any members, so it does not necessarily need to change position:
  {
    name: 'Example 3',
    members: [],
  },
  // This object named "Example 4" does not have any members, so it does not necessarily need to change position:
  {
    name: 'Example 4',
    members: [],
  },
  // This object named "Example 5" should come after its members ("Example 1"):
  {
    name: 'Example 5',
    members: [
      'Example 1',
    ],
  },
];

// The objects in "example" should also be sorted by "name" ASC, where it can not be sorted by "members".

example.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.members.includes(b.name) && b.members.includes(a.name)) {
    // Circular Reference: Skip because "a" AND "b" cannot be members of each other at the same time, so no re-ordering needed at the moment:
    return 0;
  } else if (a.members.includes(b.name) && !b.members.includes(a.name)) {
    // "a" includes "b" as a member, so "a" should come after "b":
    return 1;
  } else if (!a.members.includes(b.name) && b.members.includes(a.name)) {
    // "b" includes "a" as a member, so "b" should come after "a":
    return -1;
  } else if (!a.members.includes(b.name) && !b.members.includes(a.name)) {
    // Neither "a" nor "b" include each other as a member, so no re-ordering needed at the moment:
    return 0;
  } else {
    // OTHERWISE, use the secondary sort by "name", where it could not be sorted by "members":
    return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
  }
});

console.log(example);
```

The code above produces an **incorrect result**:

1. "Example 1"
2. "Example 3"
3. "Example 2"
4. "Example 4"
5. "Example 5"

The **correct, intended result** should be:

1. **"Example 3"**
2. **"Example 4"**
3. **"Example 1"**
4. **"Example 2"**
5. **"Example 5"**

---

**What's the best way to sort this array based on the criteria I have listed above?**

Comment: Got my butt kicked in my deleted answer, this is sorting a graph - https://github.com/marcelklehr/toposort

Comment: @Adam I am struggling to understand how to apply toposort to the question above. Any chance that you can provide an example?

Comment: Look at the [sorting dependencies](https://github.com/marcelklehr/toposort#sorting-dependencies) header - e.g. Example 4 is a dependency of Example 1. You need to first create the graph array, then just use toposort to sort it.